# How can I connect to a windows client with awx?

Tags: ansible-awx

As far as I konw about awx, it use CREDENTIAL to connect to the client host, but how can awx connect to a client host with a windows operation system such as windows 2012? If I use the machine CREDENTIAL type ,the awx will still use ssh to connect with the client host. Is there any CREDENTIAL type which is used to connect with windows host?
I have installed the winrm module and I can connect with a windows host in ansible already,but cannot in awx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ansible tower, inventories -> Details tab - > extra variables, provide the below details.

```
---
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation: true
ansible_winrm_scheme: http
ansible_port: 5985
```

Comment: So there is no solution in awx, right ? Only ansible tower supports this feature ? I cannot find any similar features in awx.

Comment: You could also use a group vars file, eg `platform_windows.yml` or `windows.yml`, if your inventory script sorts your instances into groups accordingly